# Print items in for loop vertically down in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm writing a program for school which basically works like an ordering system. At the end of every order, I have to ask the user if they want to see cumulative totals for the day (which I have stored in lists within a dictionary of items which can be ordered). I've never used pygame before and hence am kind of experimenting. I want to print my totals vertically down as part of a for loop. Here's what I have so far:

```py
pygame.init()
background_colour = (231,247,146)
(width, height) = (1000, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Running Totals')
myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 40)
myFont2 = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 20)
text = myFont.render("In store totals:", True, (0, 0, 0))
screen.fill(background_colour)
pygame.display.flip()
running = True
while running:
    screen.blit(text, (20, 20))
    for item, values in totalsdict.items():
        text2 = myFont2.render(f'{item.title()}: {values[0]}', True, (0,0,0))
        initial = 70
        screen.blit(text2, (20, initial))
        pygame.display.update()
        initial += 40
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if running == False:
            pygame.quit()
```

I had hoped that using "initial" and incrementing upwards would print each line out 20 below the other but it hasn't, and instead everything prints clumped together on one line. This is a learning curve for me so I might not have even done the for loop bit right, but does anybody know how I can get the text to print vertically down in a list?

Comment: You can upvote multiple answers, but you can just accept 1 answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the position of the first row before the loop and increment the position in the loop:

```py
row_y = 70
for item, values in totalsdict.items():
    text2 = myFont2.render(f'{item.title()}: {values[0]}', True, (0,0,0))
    screen.blit(text2, (20, row_y))
    row_y += 40
```

One update of the display at the end of the application loop is sufficient. Multiple calls to `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` cause flickering.

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(background_colour)
    screen.blit(text, (20, 20))
    
    row_y = 70
    for item, values in totalsdict.items():
        text2 = myFont2.render(f'{item.title()}: {values[0]}', True, (0,0,0))
        screen.blit(text2, (20, row_y))
        row_y += 40
    
    pygame.display.update()
        
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use pygame.font, i'll be using the same here. But pygame.freetype has more features. So consider that .

```
pygame.init()
background_colour = (231,247,146)
(width, height) = (1000, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Running Totals')
myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 40)
myFont2 = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 20)
text = myFont.render("In store totals:", True, (0, 0, 0))
screen.fill(background_colour)
pygame.display.flip()
running = True
while running:

    screen.blit(text, (20, 20))

    for event in pygame.event.get(): # event loop first
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if running == False:
            pygame.quit()

    initial = 70 # initialize this variable before the for loop
    for item, values in totalsdict.items():
        text2 = myFont2.render(f'{item.title()}: {values[0]}', True, (0,0,0))
        
        screen.blit(text2, (20, initial))
        
        initial += 40

    pygame.display.update() # update the display outside the for loop ( inside the main game loop)
```

using pygame.freetype

```
import pygame.freetype
FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont("arial", 24)
while running:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if running == False:
            pygame.quit()

    screen.blit(text, (20, 20))
    
    initial = 70
    for item, values in totalsdict.items():
        text_surface, rect = FONT.render(f'{item.title()}: {values[0]}',(0,0,0)) 
        screen.blit(text_surface, (20, initial))
    
        initial += 40

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit dude. I just realized that !